# Create list for each unique value

Tags: python, list, grouping

I'm currently looking at a table with the following structure.

```
uid | action
 1  |   A1
 1  |   A1
 1  |   A1
 1  |   A4
 2  |   A1
 2  |   A8
 2  |   A9
 3  |   A3
 3  |   A7
```

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array with the following structure.

```
[[A1, A1, A1, A4], [A1, A8, A9], [A3, A7]]
```

My idea is to keep track of a `uid` and append the actions to a list till the `uid` key changes. Once the `uid` key does change, all the actions will be appended to another array and the tracked `uid` will change to the new `uid`.

I've come up with a somewhat overblown and incorrect solution using `itertools.groupby()` but I'm not satisfied with it and am looking for something simpler. However, I've overthought this problem and am coming up with more complicated solutions.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Code:

```
data = []
for i, j in itertools.groupby(table, key=lambda x: x['uid']):
    event_array = []
    for k in list(j):
        event_array.append(k['action'])
    data.append([i, event_array])
```

Comment: If the sequence is already sorted, `itertools.groupby` would be one of the good choices here.

Comment: What is the format of the table? A sequence of two-tuples representing the rows? A dictionary?

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm a dictionary.

Comment: Alternatively, you could populate a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (or standard dict, with a tiny bit more work) with a single pass over your table rows.

Comment: @Black A dictionary how? What are the keys and what are the values?

Comment: @Black How can it be a dictionary? A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm sorry it's in a large list but within there it's json format

Comment: @Black, JSON format isn't a python type, it's a way to encode data. You can decode JSON using python, but that turns it into a python object. What is that python object? Or, if you show what the data looks like in JSON, we can figure out what kind of python object it turns into.

Comment: Based on your sample code, table probably looks something like this: ``[ {uid: 1, action: "A1"}, {uid: 2, action: "A8"}, ...]``. Is that right?

Comment: @Black Are you sure that the data is ordered?

Comment: yes, that's what it looks like. @thefourtheye, yes pretty sure as I've had to write it in sql before reading it into python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098777/create-list-for-each-unique-value#comment46428417_29098777),

> @Black Are you sure that the data is ordered?
>
> ... @thefourtheye, yes pretty sure as I've had to write it in sql before reading it into python

Since the data is already ordered, for example, like this

```
>>> data = [{'action': 'A1', 'uid': 1},
...  {'action': 'A1', 'uid': 1},
...  {'action': 'A1', 'uid': 1},
...  {'action': 'A4', 'uid': 1},
...  {'action': 'A1', 'uid': 2},
...  {'action': 'A8', 'uid': 2},
...  {'action': 'A9', 'uid': 2},
...  {'action': 'A3', 'uid': 3},
...  {'action': 'A7', 'uid': 3}]
```

you can simply use `groupby` itself, with a nested list comprehension, like this

```
>>> [[k['action'] for k in j] for i, j in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['uid'])]
[['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A4'], ['A1', 'A8', 'A9'], ['A3', 'A7']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use good old [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

DATA = [{'uid': uid, 'action': action}
        for uid, action in [(1, 'A1'),
                            (1, 'A1'),
                            (1, 'A1'),
                            (1, 'A4'),
                            (2, 'A1'),
                            (2, 'A8'),
                            (2, 'A9'),
                            (3, 'A3'),
                            (3, 'A7'),]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for data in DATA:
    d[data['uid']].append(data['action'])

print(d.values())
```

Result will be:

```
[['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A4'], ['A1', 'A8', 'A9'], ['A3', 'A7']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but it seems like `groupby` is already perfectly good.

```
uids = {}
for row in table:
    uids.setdefault(row['uid'], []).append(row['action'])

data = [uids[uid] for uid in sorted(uids.keys())]
```

The solution simply iterates over each row in the `table`, and makes sure that there is a list for the corresponding uid in the `uids` dict (using `setdefault`). Then it appends the action for that row onto the list.

So `uids` will be a dictionary whose keys are the UIDs, and values are sequences of corresponding actions from the table.

If you really want a list of lists (a "multidimensional array"), the last line uses a list comprehension to build a list whose elements are the lists of actions stored in the `uids` dict, ordered by uid.

Comment: `dict.setdefault` is old-style Python, pre-dating the availability of `defaultdict`. It is sub-optimal to `defaultdict` since it has to construct the just-in-case-the-key-is-missing argument for every call. In contrast, the `defaultdict(list)` initializes the defaultdict with a factory method, only to be called if needed. Unless you are striving for compatibility with old Python versions, use the new idioms.